# What is the recommended way to install Perl for performance?

Tags: performance, perl, installation

I'm looking for a recommended options in Configure to install Perl for max performance on a Linux CentOS6.6 64bit server with plenty of hardware resources. I'm using plenv.
Command I'm using:

```
plenv install -j 8 -Dcc=gcc $perl_to_install
```

Which -O options (and others) should I add?

And should I use threaded Perl?

Comment: The perl code you run has much more bearing on this than your perl installation.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. But every bit helps.

Comment: Using a Perl with thread support does impact the performance by about 15%, even if threads are never used.

Comment: Could you post a link to this benchmark or any other information?

Comment: But on the flip side - if you're going to use threads, and have an environment suited to it - you can substantially boost performance as a result. Of course, there's absolutely nothing stopping you having multiple versions of perl. Pretty fundamentally though, I would formally advise 'don't worry about it'. It doesn't make much difference. You'll spend _far_ more by inefficient IO, bad code, and inefficient algorithms that it's simply not worth worrying about.

Comment: The quickest and cheapest way to speed up your program is to buy faster hardware. It also speeds up all your other programs too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *“Programmers waste enormous amounts of time thinking about, or worrying about, the speed of noncritical parts of their programs, and these attempts at efficiency actually have a strong negative impact when debugging and maintenance are considered. We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil. Yet we should not pass up our opportunities in that critical 3%.”*
>
> — Donald Knuth

You need to know what options are relevant to the bottlenecks in your code

You should write your code, get it working, and then profile it using [`Devel::NYTProf`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::NYTProf). Only then can you sensibly ask a question about how best to reconfigure the perl interpreter itself

Comment: Well said. The algorithm used has far more bearing on performance than what options you used when you installed the interpreter.

Comment: @Sobrique: Indeed. And neither should be addressed until the application is complete and working. This is one of the most frustrating preoccupations, together with the idea that commenting your code is an inherently *good thing*